# root-relative path to index.htm for local website

Tags: html, local, relative-path

I have a website and need to provide a relative path to a particular file from other html files within the website. However, the website also needs to run locally and so the links are not working.

For example, I have the following structure for my webpage:

```
\---home
    |   index.htm
    |   
    +---folder1
    |   \---sub1
    |           file1.html
    |           
    +---folder2
    |   \---sub2
    |       \---sub3
    |               file2.html
    |               
    +---links |
            **link.html**
```

I need to provide through a common link that gets embedded in the `file1.html`, `file2.html`, and the `index.htm` pages, a relative path to the `link.html` file.

I tried `<a href="/links/link.htm">` and this works when my page it is hosted on a webserver, but when the page is run locally, the link resolves to `C:\links\link.html`. I need it to be where ever the index.html file is located. Like `C:\home\link\links.html` or `C:\dir1\dir2\home\links\link.html`

How do I provide a common link relative to the index.htm folder when running the webpage locally?

Thanks!
ken

Answer (score 1):

Have not done it recently... but the idea is to use ../../folder123/file.html. Two dots is upper folder and one is current folder. For simple page it is possible to trace and correct the paths  in every page (above example results to upperFolder/upperFolder/folder123/file.html) Not recomended for big projects.

When you add just slash at the begining it resolves to root. If there is dot or two dots then it is no longer root but relative path.

Better solution would be to get the address and manipulate the links with script but for simple pages using relative paths is perfect.

Guess it helps.